# Login referer not working

Tags: symfony, authentication, symfony-2.3, http-referer

I do have the following LoginEventlistener:

```
public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event) {
    if ($this->securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
        // user has just logged in
        if ($this->session->has('user_media_savings')) {
             //some code  
        }
        $referer_url = $this->container->get('request')->headers->get('referer');
        $response = new RedirectResponse($referer_url);
    }
    return $response;
}
```

If I am going to call a site which is secured, e.g. www.example.com/secured/index of course symfony2 is redirect to login page. If I now login the referer's output is the login-route not www.example.com/secured/index.

What is wrong?

Comment: Maybe you sould have a look a the 'use_referer' option : [security configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#form-login-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `_security.main.target_path` on the place where the redirect to the login action takes place, the firewall will handle the redirect to that specific route itself.

```
$redirectUrl = $this->get('router')->generate('account', array(), true)
$this->get('session')->set('_security.main.target_path', $redirectUrl);
return $this->redirectToRoute('login');
```